# Why are my sorting algorithms returning the same amount of comparisons?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

My program is supposed to run a loop that fills an array with random values, then sort the array using selection sort, enhanced bubble sort, and insertion sort. The problem is that it returns the same comparison counts every time.

Why does my code keep returning the same comparison counts?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class AssignmentIV {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testRuns = new int[4];        //stores the values for the generation of random arrays
    testRuns[0] = 10;
    testRuns[1] = 100;
    testRuns[2] = 1000;
    testRuns[3] = 10000;

    String[] algorithms = new String[3];        //stores the names of the algorithms 
    algorithms[0] = "Selection Sort";
    algorithms[1] = "Enhanced Bubble Sort";
    algorithms[2] = "Insertion Sort";

    int countComparisons;


    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)      //loops through the different algorithms
    {
        System.out.println("SORTING ALGORITHM: " + algorithms[i] + "\n");

        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)      //loops through different amounts (10, 100, 1000, 10000) of values for each algorithm
        {
            countComparisons = 0;

            int[] test = Generate(testRuns[j]);     //creates an array filled with random values

            if(algorithms[i] == "Selection Sort")
                countComparisons = selectionSort(test);             //calls the selection sort method
            else if(algorithms[i] == "Enhanced Bubble Sort")
                countComparisons = enhancedBubbleSort(test);        //calls the enhanced bubble sort method
            else if(algorithms[i] == "Insertion Sort")
                countComparisons = insertionSort(test);             //calls the insertion sort method

            System.out.println("Number of values in array: " + testRuns[j]);            //prints the number of values in the array
            System.out.println("Number of comparisons required: " + countComparisons + "\n");           //prints the number of comparisons required to sort the array
        }
    }
}


//method to populate an array with randomized integers
public static int[] Generate(int size)
{
    int[] valueArray = new int[size]; 


    //number generator is created
    Random gen = new Random();

    //each position in an array is filled with a random
    //integer up to maximum Integer.MAX_VALUE
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        valueArray[i] = gen.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    return valueArray;
}

//sorts an array using selection sort and returns the number of comparisons made
public static int selectionSort(int[] arr)
{
    int count = 0;
    int min, min_location;

    for(int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        min = arr[i];
        min_location = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < min)
            {
                min = j;
                min_location = j;
            }
            count++;
        }

        arr[min_location] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = min;
    }
    return count;
}

//sorts an array using enhanced bubble sort and returns the number of comparisons made
public static int enhancedBubbleSort(int[] arr)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < arr.length-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

//sorts an array using insertion sort and returns the number of comparisons made
public static int insertionSort(int[] arr)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j>0; j--)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[j-1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = temp;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
}
```

Here is the output:

```
SORTING ALGORITHM: Selection Sort

Number of values in array: 10
Number of comparisons required: 45

Number of values in array: 100
Number of comparisons required: 4950

Number of values in array: 1000
Number of comparisons required: 499500

Number of values in array: 10000
Number of comparisons required: 49995000

SORTING ALGORITHM: Enhanced Bubble Sort

Number of values in array: 10
Number of comparisons required: 45

Number of values in array: 100
Number of comparisons required: 4950

Number of values in array: 1000
Number of comparisons required: 499500

Number of values in array: 10000
Number of comparisons required: 49995000

SORTING ALGORITHM: Insertion Sort

Number of values in array: 10
Number of comparisons required: 45

Number of values in array: 100
Number of comparisons required: 4950

Number of values in array: 1000
Number of comparisons required: 499500

Number of values in array: 10000
Number of comparisons required: 49995000
```

Comment: all the algorithms are equally worse (`O(n^2)`), so everything seems correct

Comment: I fixed it. The count++ just needed to be moved into the if-statements in each sort method. At least I hope it outputs the correct counts.

Comment: The question is: Do you want to count all comparisons made or just the ones evaluating to true?

Comment: The assignment was worded as the former, "...the number of comparisons required for each sequence sorted.", but I think it was meant as the latter. I could be wrong though.

Comment: The number of comparisons required is the number of comparisons actually made. This number only depends on the size of the list and the implementation of the sorting algorithm. The number of comparisons evaluating to true is also dependent on the lists content too (for example if the list is already sorted)

Comment: In that case, the intention was to count the number of comparisons evaluating to be true. Thanks for explaining that distinction, it certainly helped my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of comparisons in those algorithms doesn’t depend on the values of the data. You should expect constant counts.

To see this, note that where you increment the count isn’t inside an ‘if’ statement. It’s just counting passes through the loops that drive the sort operation.

Comment: Thank you, all fixed now! I had tried to move the count into the if-statement in the selection sort, but it just changed what number it was constantly at so I changed it back. The issue was my understanding of the sorting algorithms.

Comment: Do I need to declare the question as answered? If so, where can I do that?

Comment: @Isaic02 Glad it helped.  There a round check-box button next the answer you can click.